# VBScript how to run cmd?

Tags: windows, vbscript

How to run this command via VBS?

Thanks in Advance & Best Regards.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """%comspec%"""
```

Comment: hi @MC ND, thanks for your reply. Is there a way to close the cmd windows after execution?

Comment: @raysefo, yes, you are right. `/c` is a request to execute and exit when done.